# Generate syntax highlighting for markdown in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, slim-lang

I'm using slim in my rails app to generate my views, and have enabled the markdown engine (with redcarpet) so I can write markdown in my slim files like so:

````
h2#usage Usage
markdown:
    ### Via JavaScript

    Call the dropdowns via JavaScript:

    ```js
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    ```
````

I've also enabled fenced code blocks in my `config/initializers/slim.rb`:

```
Slim::Embedded.default_options[:markdown] = {
  fenced_code_blocks: true
}
```

My question is, how how do I configure either redcarpet or another gem to generate syntax highlighting for the fenced code blocks in my markdown? I've looked into [pygments](http://pygments.org/) and [rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge), but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stitching together a few things here:

You can use the rouge gem for highlighting source code. It's pretty easy and [well documented](http://sunaku.github.io/slim-tilt-redcarpet.html) how to use it with Redcarpet. Getting Slim to use your renderer is the tricky part, but the luckily others have already fought this battle: [a pretty old github issue](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/192) and a [resulting blog post](https://github.com/jneen/rouge#you-can-even-use-it-with-redcarpet)

```
require 'rouge/plugins/redcarpet'

class HTML < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  include Rouge::Plugins::Redcarpet # yep, that's it.
end

Slim::Embedded.set_default_options markdown: {
  renderer: HTML.new,
  fenced_code_blocks: true
}
```

I haven't tested this, so the code might need some tweaking.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! One change though, I had to rename the `HTML` class. It's such a generic name, and conflicted with an existing `HTML` class. I used `RougedHTML` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A quick update - since Slim's API had changed...

I used the following code that worked for me, it both addresses the change in Slim's API and addresses the issue of the named class disrupting the namespace.

```
require 'rouge/plugins/redcarpet'
Slim::Embedded.options[:markdown] = {
        fenced_code_blocks: true,
        renderer: (Class.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML) {include Rouge::Plugins::Redcarpet} ).new
    }
```

Thank you @tmichel for the original answer.